# parse a file in java

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a development tool for a new language and here the compiler is already present. Created a model for the language. The model is tree structure. Now i need to compare the file with the model and do coloring and error detection. But i am really a beginner to eclipse development and Java. If anyone know the code to parse a file using Java.

example.xyz

```
chan example
{
    int a;
    lstnr b;
    eve new(int a , int b)
    {
        int d;
    }
    eve new1()
    {
    }
}
```

If the file is like this. `chan`, `eve` are the keywords in this. All primitive data-types are used. And a new variable called `lstnr` also present. How can i parse this file using Java.

Comment: you are beginner in java who is beginning with code parsing! Am I a bit confused here, or is that Eclipse plugin development you are talking about?

Comment: Look at Eclipse [xText](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) if you want to develop Eclipse language support

Comment: how can i develop eclipse language support without xtext. i dont have grammer of this language. and i have only one resourse the file which i given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to user the following Java libraries/framework to parse structured text.

- [Antlr](http://antlr.org/).  [Antlr Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR)
- [JFLEX](http://jflex.de/)